# How do I put a number sign in href mailto subject that will work for IE8 using MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to create an email link using MVC3 and strongly typed modeling.  I want the subject of the email to contain the # sign similar to:

```
Request #56
```

My initial attempt looked like:

```
<a href = "mailto:@Model.Email?subject=Request #@Model.ID">@Model.Name</a>
```

It resulted in what I thought was perfect HTML:

```
<a href="mailto:john.stone@nowhere.com?subject=Request #5">John Stone</a>
```

I found out that Internet Explorer does not like the # sign in the subject.  If I clicked on the above "link", the subject would be set to:

```
Request
```

After searching here, I found that I needed to use %23 in place of the #.  So my second attempt looked like:

```
<a href = "mailto:@Model.Email?subject=Request %23 @Model.ID">@Model.Name</a>
```

This resulted in the following:

```
Request # 56
```

Close but I do not want the space between the # and the number.

How do I properly use the # key without a space?

I am using MVC3 and trying to get this to work in IE8.

*added some details about the first attempt resulting html and how IE handles the subject

**SOLUTION**
There are actually two issues going on.

The first is IE will not allow the # in the subject text.  So any instance of the # needs to be replaced with %23.

The second is the MVC3 parser does NOT handle #23@Model.ID correctly.  It will NOT substitue in the value of Model.ID.

The correct solution is noted below but to "cut and paste":

```
@{   
   string requestValue = "%23" + Model.ID.ToString()
}  
<a href = "mailto:@Model.Email?subject=Request @requestValue">@Model.Name</a>
```

The above will generate a properly clickable href mail link that would look like:

```
<a href="mailto:john.stone@nowhere.com?subject=Request %235">John Stone</a>
```

When the above is clicked, the subject of the email will be "Request #5".

Comment: Have you tried deleting the space? <a href = "mailto:@Model.Email?subject=Request %23@Model.ID">@Model.Name</a>
instead of : <a href = "mailto:@Model.Email?subject=Request %23 @Model.ID">@Model.Name</a>

Comment: Deleting space resulted in: "Request #@Model.ID"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an inline C# statement.

```
@{
  string requestValue = "#" + Model.ID.ToString() // or "%23"
}

<a href = "mailto:@Model.Email?subject=Request @requestValue">@Model.Name</a>
```

Comment: My first attempt resulted in something that looked pefect in HTML: <a href="mailto:john.stone@nowhere.com?subject=Request #5">

Comment: The problem is IE8 will not process the # sign at all so when I click on the link, the Subject is just "Request".

Comment: The if the bug is specific to IE and not to MVC, then I would highly suggest not use #.  I don't know how to fix IE.

Comment: Not using the # is definitely an option but the # in the subject makes the email subject "look" better.  I know the fix for IE(don't use) but that isn't an option either :P

Comment: The above is actually the solution.  For some reason, MVC doesn't parse inline %23 correctly with @model.ID.  Adding solution code to original question post.